# gulp-ignore with gulp-jshint

Tags: javascript, gulp

I want to do a jshint on the files that is not library files like require js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var ignore = require('gulp-ignore');
gulp.task('jshint', function() {
  gulp.src('./js/src/*.js')
     .pipe(ignore.exclude('require.js'))
     .pipe(jshint())
     .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
});
```

This still reports require js

```
 C:\Work\neolivz\js\src\require.js: line 12, col 267, Too many errors. (32% scanned).
```

Any idea?

Comment: I think you should refer to it  `ignore.exlude('./path/to/require.js');` if you're using gulp-ignore?

Comment: Or just `gulp.src(['./js/src/*.js', '!**/require.js'])`.

Comment: Sorry, I was using gulp igore. I tried that also. But did not ignore.

Comment: I am able to do .src filter, which is I am doing. but I would like to now how to do it with gulp-ignore and what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 9):

You could also create a `.jshintignore` file that, just like `.gitignore`, contains files that you want to ignore.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be able to pass a regex to gulp ignore if using a specific path isn't working:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var ignore = require('gulp-ignore');
gulp.task('jshint', function() {
  gulp.src('./js/src/*.js')
     .pipe(ignore.exclude(/require\.js/))
     .pipe(jshint())
     .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
});
```